# API returning a 401 error with message "Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Getting "Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode" error while running teams API even though admin granted consent

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams"
API returning 401 error with message as shown below

{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-08-30T08:14:51",
"request-id": "8acdeb30-a9c5-434c-bfcf-ca9cbd383cbd",
"client-request-id": "8acdeb30-a9c5-434c-bfcf-ca9cbd383cbd"
}
}
}

Below are the permissions granted on app registration side

[image]

Below are the permissions granted on tenant side

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check your scopes by decoding access token in https://jwt.ms/ , make sure you have Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All permission added (screenshot 1). If its not added then you can also check if your admin granted consent or not , by checking azure portal (Screenshot 2)

**Screenshot 1**

One of the following permissions is required to call this API
[image]

**Screenshot 2**

if your admin granted consent ? You should use an Azure AD admin account to do this. The the Status will become "Granted for {your tenant}". ,
[image]

Comment: If the answer was helpful , please click on upvote to accept the answer , it will help other as well , if you have any question please click on add comment , thanks.

Comment: Hi vicky kumar, Thanks for your response. I have checked in the the scope of access token  the required permissions are present. I am attaching below the permissions listed in the scp of access token.                                                                                    "ChannelMessage.Send Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All email Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.Read.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All"

Comment: Thanks for the update , could you please provide the screenshot of status of the permission granted from the azure portal , might be it is pending with admin. thanks

Comment: I have added the screenshots of permission both on app registration side and tenant side. Could you please check if anything is missing

Comment: thanks for the update , everything looks fine ,lets someone from  MS team will take a look on this , they will help you better . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some commands are only avaiable in beta. Try 'Select-mgprofile -name "beta"'
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try beta:
Select-mgProfile -name "beta"
Worked for me